# Is my understanding of how variables work in recursive function correct?

Tags: c++, recursion

I've recently gotten to recursion in my C++ class and I was wondering is it correct to think that the scope of the variables are local to the specific stack frame:

> 3) return
>
> 2) flipString(" "); begin = a, end = t
>
> 1) flipString(at); begin = s, end = r

So when it reaches the return statement it will pop the 
third frame off,

then the 2nd frame off with s = t + " " + a

and then the first frame with s = r + at + s thus reversing the string.

```
void flipString(string &s)
{
   if (s.size() < 2)
   {
      return;
   }
   else
   {

      string begin;
      string end;      

      begin = s.at(0);
      end = s.at(s.size()-1);

      s.erase(s.begin());
      s.erase(s.end()-1);

      flipString(s); 

      s = end + s + begin;   
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: All function calls works that way. The local variables exists until the function returns, i.e. even if another function (or the same function) is called again. There is nothing special about recursion when it comes to the scope of local variables. The more interesting part of your function is that `s` is passed be reference.

Comment: You might also consider using `std::swap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three symbol-types to understand, in this context:

1. Local variables — symbols declared within a function
2. Formal parameters — symbols used as parameters within a function's implementation
3. Actual parameters — expressions passed by the caller on a function's invocation

It is also useful to understand where the values are stored and how the stack works.

A stack-frame is created for each function invocation. This creates a context for the function's execution and a reference to the caller's context. When the function exits, the function's stack frame is removed (popped) and the caller's context is restored.

Formal parameters' locations are reserved in the stack-frame of the function being invoked. Similarly, local variables are stored in the the function's stack-frame. Actual parameters or references to them are copied to the stack where they can be referenced by their formal parameter counterparts.

When the function has exited, the stack-frame is freed up along with the formal parameter and local variable space.

Note that for parameters passed as a reference (`&`) to actual values, the space for the values may exist outside the current stack-frame (only the reference address, itself, is within the stack-frame. Forgetting this can lean to confusion about why values are *persisting* across function invocations. This is more obvious with pointers, but may be overlooked when passing references.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your idea of how the function works and the function itself seem correct.

There is a different instance of the local variables begin and end in each invocation of the function, placed on the stack.

The function argument s references or points to the same string in all stack frames, because, well, it's a reference.

If a plain function argument is passed (without a reference and not as a pointer) there would be a separate copy of that argument too at each call stack level.